# Getting SQL Server error when targeting specific record in View with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand an error I'm getting in my SQL Server query. To clarify, this is a query against a VIEW, not a Table.

I can do this and get results with no errors:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [AcctId]
      ,[DocumentAmount]
  FROM [LDB].[dbo].[LG_vw_Report_AccountsReceivable]
```

The first record I see returned has an `AcctId` of 809327.

So, I would assume I could target that row and get no errors. So I try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [AcctId]
      ,[DocumentAmount]
  FROM [LDB].[dbo].[LG_vw_Report_AccountsReceivable]
  WHERE AcctId = 809327
```

But that produces this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00000DELETE' to
>   data type int.

What is this error telling me? As I mentioned I can see the row in question, and the data looks normal. So why can't I get that specific record when I query using the WHERE clause? What's happening here to cause this error?

UPDATE: This also fails:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [AcctId]
      ,[DocumentAmount]
  FROM [LDB].[dbo].[LG_vw_Report_AccountsReceivable]
  WHERE AcctId = '809327'
```

and so does this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [AcctId]
      ,[DocumentAmount]
  FROM [LDB].[dbo].[LG_vw_Report_AccountsReceivable]
  WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, AcctId) = 809327
```

Comment: What's the data type of the column `[AcctId]`?

Comment: Do you have possibility to check initial data on which View is built? Does this View have any indexes? Seems the problem is in initial data.

Comment: But then how can I get the first 1000 records from the View without error?

Comment: @Ademo when you add WHERE clause if field on which you perform filtering is included in any index it may cause re-building of indexes. Re-building does not happen when you querying without WHERE clause

Comment: @elvira.genkel...  To clarify, I believe there is actually a value somewhere with `DELETE` in the value, because elsewhere I see SELECT statements with this kind of clause: AND LM101.DOCNUMBR NOT LIKE '%DELETE%'

Comment: @Ademo yes, seems so.

Comment: @Ademo Based on the information you've in the question and in the comments, I fairly certain the problem is in the view itself.  Can you paste the code that creates the view?

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:**

The `AcctId` column is a `varchar` column, so one possible reason for this error is that the values in the `Acctid` column are implicitly converted to integers (based on the [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in T-SQL). You may try the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [AcctId], [DocumentAmount]
FROM [RKDB].[dbo].[LG_vw_Report_AccountsReceivable]
WHERE AcctId = '809327'
```

**Update:**

Of course, the statement is also important. As you can see from the next examples, the first statement returns an error:

```
SELECT x + y
FROM (VALUES (1, '1'), (2, '000DELETE')) v (x, y)
WHERE x = 2
```

but the next one executes correctly:

```
SELECT x + y
FROM (VALUES (1, '1'), (2, '000DELETE')) v (x, y)
WHERE x = 1
```

Comment: Tried this, but it produced the same error. To clarify, this is a VEW, not a Table, and when `AcctId` is being generated, I believe it's being cast as an INT.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a problem in the view.  However, a real possibility is that `AcctId` is a string.  To handle this, I would recommend

```
  WHERE AcctId = '809327'
```

You may have zero-padding as well.  If this is the case, then you need to include that in the comparison:

```
  WHERE AcctId = '000809327'
```

You could also do:

```
  WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, AcctId) = 809327
```

However, this will not use an index.

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work. As some additional info, this is a VIEW, not a Table, and when `AcctId` is being generated it's being cast as an INT.

Comment: @Ademo . . . As I say in the first sentence, the issue may be in the view.  In that case, you need to fix the view.  It is broken.

Comment: But if the view were broken, how can I get the first 1000 records? Just trying to understand. Also, to clarify, I believe there is actually a value somewhere with `DELETE` in the value, because elsewhere I see SELECT statements with this kind of clause: `AND LM101.DOCNUMBR NOT LIKE '%DELETE%'`

Comment: @Ademo You could get the first 1000 because the problem record isn't in the first 1000.

Comment: @Ademo Your view and your schema are broken. If you can't fix the schema, then someone needs to fix the view to compensate correctly for the schema problem. You cannot rely on luck to work around this. And stop assuming that rows have any particular order in a table, view, or resultset. TOP 1000 only "works" because you let the engine choose which rows to include in the resultset and it is only luck that it chooses rows that do not cause the problem.